# Parsing markup into Abstract Syntax Tree using Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, abstract-syntax-tree

This question is supplementary to: [Recursive processing of markup using Regular Expression and DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857560/recursive-processing-of-markup-using-regular-expression-and-domdocument)

The code supplied by the selected answer has been a great help to understand building a basic syntax tree. However I am now having troubles tightening the regular expressions to only match my syntax rather than `{.` but not `{{`. Ideally I would like it to only match my syntax which is:

```
{<anchor>}
{!image!}
{*strong*}
{/emphasis/}
{|code|}
{-strikethrough-}
{>small<}
```

Two tags, `a` and `small` also require differing end tags. I have tried modifying `$re_closetag` from the original code sample to reflect this but it still matches too much as text.

For example:

```
http://www.google.com/>} bang 
smäll<} boom
```

My test string is:

```
tëstïng {{ 汉字/漢字 }} testing {<http://www.google.com/>} bang {>smäll<} boom {* strông{/ ëmphäsïs {- strïkë {| côdë |} -} /} *} {*wôw*} 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either control this in the RE itself or after a match.

In the re, to control what tags may be "open" modify this part of `$re_next`:

```
(?:\{(?P<opentag>[^{\s]))  # match an open tag
      #which is "{" followed by anything other than whitespace or another "{"
```

Currently it looks for any character which is not `{` or whitespace. Simply change to this:

```
(?:\{(?P<opentag>[<!*/|>-]))
```

Now it looks for only your specific open tags.

The close tag portion only matches a single character at a time depending on what tag is open in the current context. (This is what the `$opentag` argument is for.)  So to match a pair of characters, simply change the `$opentag` to look for in the recursive call. E.g.:

```
        if (isset($m['opentag']) && $m['opentag'][1] !== -1) {
            list($newopen, $_) = $m['opentag'];

            // change the close character to look for in the new context
            if ($newopen==='>') $newopen = '<';
            else if ($newopen==='<') $newopen = '>';

            list($subast, $offset) = str_to_ast($s, $offset, array(), $newopen);
            $ast[] = array($newopen, $subast);
        } else if (isset($m['text']) && $m['text'][1] !== -1) {
```

Alternatively, you can keep the RE as-is and decide what to do with the match after the fact. For example, if you match a `@` character but `{@` is not an allowed open tag, you can either raise a parse error or simply treat it as a text node (attaching `array('#text', '{@')` to the ast), or anything in between.